# C# | error "Could not find a part of the path" in a written program that should unzip an file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, zip

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace TF2DuckHitSound
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int version = 1;
            string sourcePath = @".\TF2DuckHitSounds2.1\";
            string destPath = @".\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\custom\";
            string sourceZIP = @".\TF2DuckHitSound2.1\duckhitsound.zip";
            string destPathAlt;
            bool destPathExist;


            Console.WriteLine($"Installer for TF2DuckHitsound. Version {version}");
            Console.WriteLine("Looking for TF2 Directory...");
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(destPath))
            {
                destPathExist = true;
            }
            else
            {
                destPathExist = false;
                Console.WriteLine("TF2 Directory not found!");
            }
            if (destPathExist == true)
            {
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcePath, sourceZIP);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceZIP, destPath);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the full path of your custom directory...");
                destPathAlt = Console.ReadLine();
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcePath, sourceZIP);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceZIP, destPathAlt);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Pls help. Here is the exact error code:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\luca-\OneDrive\Visual Studio\TF2DuckHitSound\TF2DuckHitSound\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\TF2DuckHitSound2.1\duckhitsound.zip'.

Comment: where is the file supposed to exist?

Comment: in theory in your downloads folder, because this program is supposed to install a mod for a game.

Comment: is the zip file present in the source of your directory: "sourceZIP". Your Source directory is: ```C:\Users\luca-\OneDrive\Visual Studio\TF2DuckHitSound\TF2DuckHitSound\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\TF2DuckHitSound2.1```

Comment: no actually dont. but that dosent make sense. why does c# autotarget the path that i used at the beginning.

Comment: Error message says that the file is not present :) Can you validate that it is with same name and retry your code

Comment: Please move the file to some place that can be accessed (outside of your Release folder) then try again.

Comment: Also, since it's a Users path, make sure that the process running the application has rights to that folder.